# how to let dataset add my own custom information when createorreplaceview in sparksql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, catalog

I use createOrReplaceView to register a temp view in sparksql catalog, this method just need one parameter (string viewname), but I need add my own custom information, like a hashMap stored some information I need, is there a good way to do this?

1. I know I can use a hashmap in my own project

you can see in spark source code there is a method:

```
CreateViewCommand(
  name = tableIdentifier,
  userSpecifiedColumns = Nil,
  comment = None,
  properties = Map.empty,
  originalText = None,
  child = logicalPlan,
  allowExisting = false,
  replace = replace,
  viewType = viewType)
```

but we can not pass properties, even we can not pass table description information

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the usecase- but you can do that using spark sql (no direct api to add table properties, so you can consider this as indirect way)-

```
/**
   * Create or replace a view. This creates a [[CreateViewStatement]]
   *
   * For example:
   * {{{
   *   CREATE [OR REPLACE] [[GLOBAL] TEMPORARY] VIEW [IF NOT EXISTS] multi_part_name
   *   [(column_name [COMMENT column_comment], ...) ]
   *   create_view_clauses
   *
   *   AS SELECT ...;
   *
   *   create_view_clauses (order insensitive):
   *     [COMMENT view_comment]
   *     [TBLPROPERTIES (property_name = property_value, ...)]
   * }}}
   */
```

visit here for more information-
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/parser/AstBuilder.scala#L3493

Sample query-

```
 val viewQuery =
      s"""
        | CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW new_test
        | COMMENT 'this is view comment'
        | TBLPROPERTIES ('creator'='som', 'createdTime'=${System.currentTimeMillis()})
        | AS select * from test
      """.stripMargin

    sqlContext.sql(viewQuery)
```

Comment: my use case is I will create a dataframe with sparksesession, then I use createOrReplaceView to register view to spark catalog. at the same time ,I want to keep some other information regarding the dataset.

Comment: Hi, have you tried the command mentioned above? i think it will solve your purpose

Comment: HI have you tried the answer? if it works. please accept and upvote